# Auto-suggestion Javascript event

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have one text box field. When I type in it the auto-suggest pop-up will appear. I want to control how many numbers or characters are in texbox field when I click in suggested number or text (in auto-suggest box) and not when I type in texboxt field. With other words the value that should be counted for numbers  is the one that comes from autosuggestion not the one that you start to type before auto suggestion appears.

Html part:

```
<div class="label-hs">{{ form_label(form.product,'Product') }}</div>
    <div class="hscodes6-collections">
        {% for product in form.product %}
            {{ form_widget(product) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript part:

```
$( ".hscodes6-collections input[type=text]" ).combogrid({
 url: "{{ path('app_app_search_index_combogridsix') }}",
    debug:true,
    replaceNull: true,
    colModel: [{'columnName':'hscode','width':'30','label':'Product'},{'columnName':'description','width':'60','label':'Description'}],

    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( event.target ).val( ui.item.hscode );
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of your javascript and the corresponding html?

Comment: Please post your code that produces the problem, otherwise we cannot help you with it.

Comment: I edited my question. That is my code html and javascript.

Comment: Jao honksha motrat krejtve se nuk paskeni lidhje. Motrat ne pidh krejt jao qifsha.